# How to get Push Notifications working for React Native Expo app

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo, apple-push-notifications, android-push-notification

I recently noticed that notifications for a mobile app I work on no longer work.

I had a thought this morning, and think it could be down to how we build the app now. Previously, we used the now deprecated `expo build`, and had issues migrating to `eas build`. We overcame this and now use `npx expo prebuild` to generate teh Android and iOS folders, which we can then pop into Android Studio and Xcode respectively.

I think that previously, `expo build` handled the push notification stuff, and we are now missing something that is causing them to no longer work.

I have been doing some digging over the last day, and saw that in my `Identifiers` for iOS, there was a prompt to configure some certificates for the Push Notifications, which we didn't have. I have since followed the steps to generate these, along with the `.p12` files, but I am unsure of where to go from here?

The process for building our iOS app, is once the `npx expo prebuild` has completed, I drag the folder into Xcode, handle the signing and build settings, then configure my `Gymfile`, and then run `fastlane gym` to generate my `.ipa` file which I can upload to Apple/TestFlight no issue.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are running `npx expo prebuild`? You can build the app binaries for both Android and IOS using EAS build services which do not need any extra configuration steps.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get push notifications working for my React Native app.

So I followed the documentation for iOS and Android respectively, and went down the path of APNs and FCM.

So I retrieve my `deviceToken` from the application, which i securely store in my server database. Then, when a given event occurs that I want to send a notification for, I use the APN and FCM node modules to handle the notification.